# Python local variable and global variable search

Tags: python, namespaces, global, local

Here is my code:

```
abc=0  
def a():     
    abc+=1  
    print abc
```

And when I execute this function:

```
a()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in abc
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'abc' referenced before assignment
```

I can fix this problem by adding `global abc` in function, But my question is why python interpretor can not decide if some thing is not in local space then search for global and assign value from there.

It does for printing a global variable in local space but not for assignment?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using the same name for a local variable and the function?

Comment: Because for basic assignment `=`, it would be very easy to accidentally introduce a global variable that radically changed the behaviour of any functions with conflicting names. The combined assignment operators like `+=` follow.

Comment: You are inviting problems if you have a function called `a` and a global variable also called `a`. Give better names for things.

Comment: You misunderstand the error. You get the error because you didn't assign any value to `a`.

Comment: adding `global a` does not *fix* this, instead leads to `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'function' and 'int'`, perhaps your *actual* code was like `a = 1`, `def f(): global a a += 1`

Comment: @meissner_ They did define `a` (as a function in the global namespace) and then they tried to add an integer to it, which fails first because it looks for `a` in the local namespace, and 2nd because adding integers and functions is nonsensical

Comment: I think i have pasted variable name wrongly. have edited it again

Answer (score 1):

Edit 1: Updated code from your wrong variable name and comment.

Edit 2: Added example increment code.

You have to assign "abc" variable in function even you assign as global variable.

```
# if assign global abc
global abc

def a(): 
    # must assign variable "abc" 
    abc = 0     
    abc += 1  
    print abc

 a()
 # print 1
```

Increment sample code.

```
abc = 0

def a():
    global abc
    abc = abc + 1

a()
# every times call a() plus 1 to abc.

print abc
# print 1
```